# How Hyperledger Composer checks the model namespace

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I want to change the namespace in my model code (mymodel.cto)  different from (org.acme.sample). I'm trying to create the Business Network Definition  with:

```
composer archive create....
```

I received the following error:

```
IllegalModelException: Failed to find namespace org.mymodel
```

I know that with Hyperledger Composer, you can't change the domain, but this is with my own local instance of Hyperledger Composer. How can I set my own domain on the Business Network Definition?

Comment: not sure why - can you post your model file (in a code block) please?  What happens when you paste it into the Online Playground to test (Model file) -> https://composer-playground.mybluemix.net/editor does it validate (see messages at the bottom). Also can you paste the full `composer archive create` command that you ran..Lastly, you say you changed the domain 'locally' - but did you have references to the 'old namespace' in your code (eg. script file or permissions.acl file etc etc)

Answer (score 1):

I just delete the file permissions.acl (with had the correct domain) and it works ...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it was because of a mismatch in naming convention.  Some of the tutorials have the model file in a sub-namespace, i.e. org.myorg.myapp.model
where all the references in the logic.js & queries.js also referred to the models in org.myorg.myapp.model, but I tried to use the 'top level' namespace 'org.myorg.myapp' in the permissions.acl

When I changed the namespace (and references) to org.myorg.myapp (i.e. removed the .model) then it matched what was in the permissions.acl and worked.

So I don't think the correct answer is to remove your acl but to fix the name mismatch.